# python function throws and error while trying to convert datetime string '12/20/2018 11:02:34:933' to datetime object

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Facing challenges while trying to convert date string to date time object. This date and time is being read from a log file. i was able to read other formats using python but this format is not readable `12/20/2018 11:02:34:933`

```
op_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/20/2018 11:02:34:933', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Error

> ValueError: time data '12/20/2018 11:02:34:933' does not match format
>   '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error says, your format does not match the example you gave.

Your format has two issues:

1. In your example the seconds and microseconds are separated by a colon, your format specifies a dot.
   11:02:34(:)933 vs %H:%M:%S(.)%f
2. You switched day and month. A month with the ordinal 20 does not exist.

Try this

```py
op_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('12/20/2018 11:02:34:933', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried changing the dot to colon too. Still the same error.

Comment: You have another issue I overlooked. I updated my answer and validated that it's working now.

Comment: My bad. I have also updated the month and date and tried still not working. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: I have verified that the code I posted above is working in python 2 and 3 on my machine. Maybe you still have a typo somewhere? Have you tried just copy and pasting the example code?

Comment: Typo it is. Thank you so much heilerich for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked. I‘d appreciate it if you would accept the answer if this solved your problem.